# My problem is about drawables which are oversize on screens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new to programming, my drawables are oversize in some devices. I created images with *various pixels*, then I created *various drawable* directories naming dpi levels. Then I put images in drawable according to dpi levels. Still in some phone images are oversize. how can I fit images to all screen size?

Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.Linlayout);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starblack);
        linearLayout.addView(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code with a verifiable example and perhaps images to clarify your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I post the answer which is the simplest way to manage your drawable for different screen sizes.

Comment: Did you tried scaleType to fitCenter (if you are using imageview) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Naveen. i created 16 buttons (4*4) programaticaly with for loop . then i set drawable to each but in some phones it doesnt fit screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do. if you have better way i would like to hear it to learn also. my solution:

```
    int h = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._75sdp);
    int w = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._75sdp);
    setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to make things easier for you to manipulate drawable in different screen sizes.

Here is the [Library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

You can use just one max size drawable xxxhdpi and put the height and width in SDP it will manage itself for all screens

**For example like this**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_9sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

It is the simplest way to manage your drawables according to different screens.

**UPDATED**

For programmatically set the height and width in **SDP like this:**

```
button.getLayoutParams().width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._52sdp);
button.getLayoutParams().height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._58sdp);
```

**OR**

```
button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._58sdp), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._52sdp))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i put drawables in buttons/imagebuttons which i created programaticaly. is there a way to set layout width and height programaticaly?

Comment: I tired as you suggested but it gives complier error(error: cannot find symbol variable _40sdp). then i created dimen.xml file and get dimen values from there it compiles succesfully but it gives runtime error. i tried also setheight(R.dimen.mydimen) but it also gives runtime error. thanks though.

Comment: @ErkinCakir did you add this [library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) in your project??

Comment: @ErkinCakir I think you haven't added the dependency in your project.

Comment: Tanveer Munir. i learned library and sdp concept  thanks to you. it will help me alot. but Unfortunately i still couldnt set layoutwidth and layoutheight of Button which i created programatically.  i tried your code  above it closes app at start. i tried 'button.setwidth(R.dimen._52sdp)' also. it didnt work either.

Comment: @ErkinCakir can you post your code of creation button?

Comment: @ErkinCakir it gives me to understanding to which you're doing? please add your code

Comment: thanks @Tanveer Munir with your help i found my solution.

Comment: @ErkinCakir please have to look my update answer also.

Comment: I checked your updated answer. it is same as i did. just i created two int to get width and height then i put in LayoutParam. you on the other hand did it directly inside LayoutParam.

Comment: Yeah exactly I did the same